# What does it mean "congruence properties of character values"

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I am reading from *Inverse Galois Theory*  by Gunter Malle

In the proof of a proposition, I came across this "congruence properties of character values" .

What does he mean by "congruence properties of character values "?

[image]

Comment: I guess it means that the character is always invariant under conjugation, i.e. $\chi(hgh^{-1})=\chi(g)$ for all $g,h\in G$.

Comment: @Hanno Yes, that's right, character is a class function, it is constant on conjugacy classes, but here $3A$ and $3B$ are two different conjugacy classes.